# Polycyclic groups and Group extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have a SES $1\to N\to G\to G/N\to 1$, and assume that $G/N$ is polycyclic. What condition on $N$ will ensure that $G$ is polycyclic? THanks.

Comment: $G$ is polycyclic if and only if $N$ and $G/N$ are both polycyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $G$ is [polycyclic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycyclic_group) if it is solvable and Noetherian. It's a [standard result](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_is_Solvable_iff_Normal_Subgroup_and_Quotient_are_Solvable) that $G$ is solvable if and only if $G/N$ and $N$ are solvable.

If $N$ is not Noetherian, then $G$ is not Noetherian: any subgroup of $N$ is also a subgroup of $G$. Conversely, suppose that $N$ is Noetherian. For any subgroup $H <G$, $H/H\cap N \simeq HN/N$. Since $G/N$ is Noetherian, this implies $H/H\cap N$ is generated by the cosets of some finite set $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\} \subset G$. Since $N$ is Noetherian, some $\{b_1,\dots,b_k\}$ generates $H \cap N$. It follows that $H$ is finitely generated by $\{a_1,\dots,a_n, b_1,\dots,b_k\}$. This shows $G$ is Noetherian if and only if $N$ and $G/N$ are Noetherian, and hence $G$ is polycyclic if and only if $G$ and $G/N$ are polycyclic.