# Extension of a virtually polycyclic group by a virtually polycyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to prove that an extension of a virtually polycyclic group by a virtually polycyclic group is virtually polycyclic, and I see no reference. I do see a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900420/polycyclic-groups-and-group-extension) of the analogous statement with "virtually" removed.

My attempt:

Given $1\to N\to G\to G/N\to 1$, we may assume $G/N$ is polycyclic, since any subgroup $T$ of $G/N$ is of the form $G'/N$ with $G'$ a subgroup of $G$ of the same index as $T$ (hence finite if $T$ was the finite index polycyclic subgroup). Now, given $S<N$ polycylic, if we further assume that $S$ is normal then we may use $1\to S\to G\to G/S\to 1$ to show that $G$ is virtually polycyclic (we show that $G/S$ is virtually polycyclic using the extension $1\to N/S \to G/S\to G/N\to 1$ and then repeat the trick above lifting a finite index subgroup of $G/S$ to a finite index subgroup of $G$).

Of course, $S$ need not be normal, and hence the natural candidate would be to use its normalizer in $G$. The problem is I can't prove that the normalizer has finite index in $G$ (using that $S$ has finite index with respect to a normal subgroup). Any help?

Comment: If S  is the policyclic subgroup of N, then the intersection of all subgroups the same index as S is both finite index and characteristic in N.

Comment: Why is it finite index? There may be infinitely many subgroups the same index as S...

Comment: Since $N$ is virtually polycyclic, there exists a polycyclic subgroup of $N$ having finite  index in $N$, and that subgroup is $S$. Since $S$ has finite index in $N$, and since $S$ is contained in the normalizer of $S$ in $N$, it follows that the normalizer of $S$ in $N$ has finite index in $N$.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. My question "why is it finite index" was about Steve D's example. Steve D wasn't referring to the normalizer in N (which doesn't work for this argument since it is not normal in G). He was referring to the intersection of all subgroups of N having the same index as S, i.e. a subgroup which is smaller (not larger) than S.

Comment: Since S is finitely generated, so is N...

Comment: Actually, since this is an important trick when dealing with virtually Blah groups, I will outline why the characteristic subgroup I mentioned above is finite index. If you wanna work it out yourself, don't read any further. I claim that for a fixed index n, every f.g. group has only finitely many subgroups of index n. This follows by noting that, for any such subgroup, the coset action induces a (uniquely determined) homomorphism into S_n. Since S_n is finite, and the group is f.g., there are only finitely many such homomorphism  (just thinking about where the generators go)

Comment: Yes, but as far as I can see two different subgroups of index n may induce the same uniquely determined homomorphism into S_n.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see how the trick works, you take $S'$ a subgroup of $S$ that is normal in $N$ and of minimal finite index among such $S'$ (this is well-defined because the normal core of $S$ has finite index). Then this $S'$ must be characteristic because any automorphism would send $S'$ to some $S''$ having the same maximal property and if $S'\neq S''$ we take $S'S''$ which is polycyclic, finite index and normal but has strictly smaller index, contradicting minimality.

Comment: No they cannot, as the stabilizer of the point 1 is exactly the subgroup in question.

Comment: Also, just read the rest of your post. You seem to be assuming N/S is polycyclic; it's not. You only know it's finite. What you are trying to prove is true though

Comment: @EvaristoCarriego: Do you have any further questions?

Comment: Oh, no! I was going to thank you but there was a message box saying there were too many comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof of the question in the title.

Suppose we have the extension
$$ 1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow G/N\rightarrow1$$
where both $N$ and $G/N$ are virtually polycyclic.  As already claimed in the OP, we can safely assume $G/N$ is polycyclic.  By the discussion in the comments, there is a subgroup $S\le N$ such that $S$ is normal in $G$ and $N/S$ is finite. We thus have the extension
$$ 1\rightarrow N/S \rightarrow G/S\rightarrow G/N\rightarrow1$$
and we want to prove $G/S$ is virtually polycyclic (since then, with $S$ polycylic, $G$ would be virtually polycyclic).

So to rephrase, we have
$$ 1\rightarrow F\rightarrow H\rightarrow P\rightarrow1$$
with

1. $F$ finite
2. $P$ polycyclic

and we want to show $H$ is virtually polycyclic.  We do so by induction on the the cyclic series length of $P$; that is, we can write
$$ 1 < P_1 < P_2 < \cdots < P_{n-1} < P_n=P$$
where the successive quotients $P_{i+1}/P_i$ are cyclic. We are then inducting on $n$.

When $n=0$, $P$ is the trivial group, and then $H=F$ is a finite group, and thus clearly virtually polycyclic.

Now take the pre-image of $P_{n-1}$ in $H$ (call it $K$): this is a normal subgroup of $H$, which by the induction hypothesis, is virtually polycyclic.

If $H/K$ is finite, then $H$ is also virtually polycyclic, and we are done.

If $H/K$ is infinite, we have the extension
$$ 1\rightarrow K\rightarrow H\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow1$$
and since $\mathbb{Z}$ is free, this extension splits: there is an infinite cyclic subgroup $L\le H$ such that $KL=H$. But if $Q\le K$ is the normal polycyclic subgroup that makes $K$ virtually p.c., then $QL$ is a finite index polycyclic subgroup of $H$.